# Read Commited and Read Uncommited in microsoft sql server in an example

Tags: sql, sql-server

This question is more of a theoretical one.

Let's say that you have the table **Employees**:

| id | name | salary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Stanley | 500 |
| 2 | Jan | 600 |
| 3 | Zaid | 700 |

Let's also say that I have 2 transactions:

T1:

```sql
 Begin Transaction
 S1: update Employees set salary = 2*salary where name = ‘Zaid’
 S2: update Employees set salary = 3*salary where name = ‘Zaid’
 Commit;
```

T2:

```sql
 Begin Transaction
 S3: update Employees set salary = salary - 20 where name = ‘Zaid’
 S4: update Employees set salary = salary - 10 where name = ‘Zaid’
 Commit;
```

Let's also say that T1 is executed with isolation level of "Read Uncommitted"
and T2  is executed with isolation level of "Read Committed"

How can will they execute?

My thought process is something like this: `@value = the original value of zaid's salary`

| Time | Transaction 1 | Transaction 2 | Salary *(value of the salary at the given time)* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Begin Transaction |  | @value |
| 1 | S1 | Begin Transaction | 2 * @value |
| 2 |  | S3 | @value - 20 |
| 3 | S2 |  | 3*(2*value -20) |
| 4 |  | S4 | (@value - 20) - 10 |
| 5 | Commit; |  | *[this is where I think I lost it completely]* 3*(2*value -20) |
| 6 |  | Commit; | (@value - 20) - 10 ? |

As I understand "Read Uncommitted" means that the Transaction 1 will read any changes that will happen on the table from transaction 2, even though they are not committed
and "Read Committed" means that the transaction 2 will read only the committed changes from any other transaction. If they are not committed is like they have not happened yet

But how do those two work together? What will happen? Can we know how will they interact? Is the chart I made even remotely accurate?

---

**UPDATE**

I just read in Microsoft's web site that:

> READ UNCOMMITTED is the least restrictive isolation level because **it ignores locks placed by other transactions**. Transactions executing under READ UNCOMMITTED can read modified data values that have not yet been committed by other transactions; these are called "dirty" reads.

Does this means that if the 2nd transaction started first, will the first one wait for it to be committed, or will it ignore any exclusive locks that transaction 2 made and place it's own locks?

So it will be something like this:

| Time | Transaction 1 | Transaction 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 |  | Begin Transaction |
| 1 | Begin Transaction | S3 |
| 2 | S1 |  |
| 3 | S2 |  |
| 4 | Commit; |  |
| 5 |  | S4 |
| 6 |  | Commit; |

Comment: I found [this article](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/) has a good explanation with examples, it's some reading though

Comment: I was half expecting that link to be an Erland Sommarskog article, with your *"it's some reading though"* comment, @GuidoG . ;)

Comment: I read the article plus [this one](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/12/read-committed-snapshot-isolation-writers-block-rcsi/). As I understand, if we have "Read Committed" and "Read Uncommitted" running at the same time we cannot know how they are gonna be executed. But if you run 2 "Read Uncommitted" Transactions together the writers block writers but not readers.

Comment: _Can we know how will they interact?_ Yes - you open two query windows in SSMS, put one batch in the first and one batch in the second along with the appropriate `set transaction isolation level` statement. Then run those batches line by line, stopping where needed to switch between the two sessions and evaluate your results.

Comment: @Larnu yes, it seems shorter than I remember it. Should have checked it better before saying that :)

Comment: Why would you want to use `READ UNCOMMITTED` anyway? Do you *want* incorrect results and deadlocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data modifications will take exclusive locks regardless of the isolation level so the `UPDATE` statement will block when an attempt is made to update an row not yet committed by the other session.

It is also possible a deadlock will occur if the sessions are waiting on each other.

Comment: So, if the first transaction begins and reaches the S1, it will lock all other updates from any other transaction until it ends. So practically, the 2nd transaction will update the table after the first one has been committed. Right?

Comment: @BrainlessPOMO, correct, S3 will wait until T1 commits. So the actual order of statement completion would be 0, 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6 and T2 would use the after update values of T1.

Comment: If I recall correctly, `READ UNCOMMITTED` does not take U-locks at the read phase, so the likelihood of a deadlock when the X-lock is taken at the write phase is higher.